# python/twisted, t.w.s.Site: safe shutdown

Tags: python, service, twisted, shutdown

Having

```
class CnxAwareSite(server.Site):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        server.Site.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.cnx_cnt = 0

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        channel = server.Site.buildProtocol(self, addr)

        def cntCnxMade(f):
            self.cnx_cnt += 1
            print 'new conn', self.cnx_cnt

            return f
        channel.connectionMade = cntCnxMade(channel.connectionMade)

        def cntCnxLost(f):
            def post_wrap(result):
                self.cnx_cnt -= 1
                return result

            return lambda *args, **kwargs: post_wrap(f(*args, **kwargs))
        channel.connectionLost = cntCnxLost(channel.connectionLost)

        return channel
...

site = CnxAwareSite(root)
site.port = reactor.listenTCP(PORT, site)
```

and having installed a trigger, performing async-looping checks for site.cnx_cnt deferred-chained to a site.port.stopListening()

```
reactor.addSystemEventTrigger('before', 'shutdown', shutdown, site)
```

is it the right way to ensure the 'clean shutdown' of the service before stopping the reactor?

Using twistd is not an option for me... (sigh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *general*, you've got basically the right idea.  Your `shutdown` function (which is not shown, so I can't be sure about it) can return a `Deferred` that fires when any necessary cleanup is complete.  However, I always make the relevant code into an [`IService`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.1.0/api/twisted.application.service.IService.html), and then do `reactor.addSystemEventTrigger('before', 'shutdown', myService.stopService)`; this makes it easier to test and it makes it possible to integrate your service into a `twistd` plugin service hierarchy later, if that possibility becomes available to you.

*Specifically*, however, you don't need to do this just to stop listening on a port.  The reactor will automatically handle that for you at shutdown time.  Also: what do you mean by "performing async-looping checks"?  If you're just waiting for the connection count to get to zero, then you should just fire a `Deferred` when it gets to zero, you shouldn't be looping.

(More detail in your code sample would be useful to address some of these issues.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Glyph. Your tip is in any case worth to follow :)